# nested flexbox ignores flexbasis and stacks items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to build a layout with three columns. 
Two of these columns will each contain two rows. 
Each leaf-item will contain a div that I use for displaying a background image.

The main div should keep its ratio therefor it has a padding-bottom:xx% attribute.

Why does flexbox stack the row items? 
And why does it ignore the flex-basis in the flex attribute?

html:

```
<div class="vodReco_hub">
  <div id="col_left">
    <div id="vertical_large" >
      <div id="image_box"  
           style="background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/400/400/')"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="col_mid">
    <div id="horizontal_medium_top">
      <div id="image_box"  
           style="background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/400/400/')"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="horizontal_medium_bottom">
      <div id="image_box"  
           style="background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/400/400/')"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="col_right">
    <div id="horizontal_small_top">
      <div id="image_box"  
           style="background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/400/400/')"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="horizontal_small_bottom">
      <div id="image_box"  
           style="background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/400/400/')"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.vodReco_hub
{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;

  background-color: blue;
}
.vodReco_hub #image_box
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;


  background-color: yellow;
}
.vodReco_hub #col_left
{
  flex-basis: 38%;


  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}   
.vodReco_hub #col_mid
{
  flex-basis: 38%;


  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.vodReco_hub #col_right
{
  flex-basis: 24%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbJNNQ

Comment: You're re-using the ID `#image` ...you can't do that.

Comment: Why that? Is this some kind of reserved keyword?

Comment: changed #image to #image_box. does not change a thing though

Comment: No, but IDs should be unique on a page. That's the point of any ID (whether web or not)..you can't have two the same. If you need to have the same styles on several items...use a **class**.

Answer (score 0):

Your IDs were converted to classes.

```
  <div class="col_left">
    <div class="vertical_large" >
```

This [codepen](http://codepen.io/systemaddict/pen/PGwOOV) illustrates some of the fixes necessary to approach what I believe you're talking about.

Not to be rude but if you're not sure when to use class or ID then you should start at HTML/CSS basics, then tackle flexbox.

Adding padding to bottom of flexbox has nothing to do with keeping aspect ratio.

Flexbox was not stacking the rows.

The flex-basis question was a great one. This is kind of tricky. So you were creating a 100% of 0 size elements. Unfortunately, HTML doesn't have some magic way of understanding that the background should be included within the sizing of the parent. 100% is a relation of self to parent. If I'm showing a background at 100% of my parent's size... it doesnt help if my parent is size 0.

Comment: I know it's temping to hack your way to a solution, but if you're experimenting **in the very least** post minimal and organized code to stack overflow.

Comment: also, flexbox is easiest to understand when you just deal with it in terms of rows and columns. slice into it this way. Dont think in terms of labeling  each and every part. You're building a container out of flexbox, not the content itself.